# Unable to change x position of legend text inside a group element using D3

Tags: d3.js, visualization, legend

I am trying to create a horizontal graph legend in D3.js.  I am using a group element (g) as a container for all the legends and the individual legends (text) are also each wrapped inside a "g" element.  The result is that the individual legends are stacked on top of each other rather than spaced out.
I have tried changing the x attribute on the legends and also transform/translate.  Whilst the DOM shows that the x values are applied the legends don't move. So if the DOM shows the legend / g element is positioned at x = 200 it is still positioned at 0.
I have spent two days trying to solve this and probably looked at over 50 examples including anything I could find on StackExchange.
Below code is my latest attempt.  It doesn't through any error and the x values are reflected in the DOM but the elements just won't move.

I have included the code covering the relevant bits (but not all code).

The legend container is added here:

```
/*<note>Add container to hold legends. */
        var LegendCanvas = d3.select("svg")
            .append("g")
                .attr("class", "legend canvas")
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", 0)
                .attr("width", Width)
                .style("fill", "#ffcccc")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0,15)");
```

There is then a loop through a json array of objects:

```
        var PrevElemLength = 0;

        /*<note>Loop through each data series, call the Valueline variable and plot the line. */
        Data.forEach(function(Key, i) {
            /*<note>Add the metric line(s). */
            Svg.append("path")
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("data-legend",function() { return Key.OriginId })
                /*<note>Iterates through the data series objects and applies a different color to each line. */
                .style("stroke", function () {
                    return Key.color = Color(Key.UniqueName); })
                .attr("d", Valueline(Key.DataValues));

            /*<note>Add a g element to the legend container. */
            var Legend = LegendCanvas.append("g")
                .attr("class", "legend container")
                .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
                    if (i === 0) {
                        return "translate(0,0)"
                    } else { 
                        PrevElemLength += this.previousElementSibling.getBBox().width;
                        return "translate(" + (PrevElemLength) + ",0)"
                    }
                });

            /*<note>Adds a rectangle to pre-fix each legend. */
            Legend.append("rect")
                .attr("width", 5)
                .attr("height", 5)
                .style("fill", function () {
                    return Key.color = Color(Key.UniqueName); });

            /*<note>Adds the legend text. */
            Legend.append("text")
                .attr("x", function() {
                    return this.parentNode.getBBox().width + 5;
                })
                /*.attr("y", NetHeight + (Margin.bottom/2)+ 10) */
                .attr("class", "legend text")
                .style("fill", function () {
                    return Key.color = Color(Key.UniqueName); })
                .text(Key.UniqueName);
```

Here is a screen shot of what the output looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mpkN.jpg)
Any help on how to create a horizontal legend (without over lapping legends) would be much appreciated. Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using local variables `d` and `i` as function parameters while setting the `transform` attribute. Parameter `i` in local scope overrides the actual variable. The value of local variable i would be always zero as there is no data bind to that element.

```
var Legend = LegendCanvas.append("g")
   .attr("class", "legend container")
   .attr("transform", function (d, i) { //Remove i
       if (i === 0) {
          return "translate(0,0)"
       } else { 
          PrevElemLength += this.previousElementSibling.getBBox().width;
          return "translate(" + (PrevElemLength) + ",0)"
       }
  });
```

I have also made slight updates to the code for improvements.

```js
var LegendCanvas = d3.select("svg")
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend canvas")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", 500)
  .style("fill", "#ffcccc")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,15)");
var PrevElemLength = 0;
var Data = [{
  OriginId: 1,
  UniqueName: "Some Long Text 1"
}, {
  OriginId: 2,
  UniqueName: "Some Long Text 2"
}];
/*<note>Loop through each data series, call the Valueline variable and plot the line. */
var Color = d3.scale.category10();
Data.forEach(function(Key, i) {

  /*<note>Add a g element to the legend container. */
  var Legend = LegendCanvas.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend container")
    .attr("transform", function() {
      if (i === 0) {
        return "translate(0,0)"
      } else {
        var marginLeft = 5;
        PrevElemLength += this.previousElementSibling.getBBox().width;
        return "translate(" + (PrevElemLength + marginLeft) + ",0)"
      }
    });

  /*<note>Adds a rectangle to pre-fix each legend. */
  Legend.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 5)
    .attr("height", 5)
    .style("fill", function() {
      return Key.color = Color(Key.UniqueName);
    });

  /*<note>Adds the legend text. */
  Legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", function() {
      return this.parentNode.getBBox().width + 5;
    })
    .attr("dy", "0.4em")
    .attr("class", "legend text")
    .style("fill", function() {
      return Key.color = Color(Key.UniqueName);
    })
    .text(Key.UniqueName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg height=500 width=500></svg>
```

The d3 way of implementation(Using data binding) would be as follows

```js
var LegendCanvas = d3.select("svg")
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend canvas")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", 500)
  .style("fill", "#ffcccc")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,15)");

var Data = [{
  OriginId: 1,
  UniqueName: "Some Long Text 1"
}, {
  OriginId: 2,
  UniqueName: "Some Long Text 2"
}];

var Color = d3.scale.category10();

var Legend = LegendCanvas.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(Data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend container");  

Legend.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 5)
  .attr("height", 5)
  .style("fill", function(Key) {
    return Key.color = Color(Key.UniqueName);
  });

Legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", function() {
    return this.parentNode.getBBox().width + 5;
  })
  .attr("dy", "0.4em")
  .attr("class", "legend text")
  .style("fill", function(Key) {
    return Key.color = Color(Key.UniqueName);
  })
  .text(function(Key){ return Key.UniqueName });

var PrevElemLength = 0;
Legend.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    if (i === 0) {
      return "translate(0,0)"
    } else {
      var marginLeft = 5;
      PrevElemLength += this.previousElementSibling.getBBox().width;
      return "translate(" + (PrevElemLength + marginLeft) + ",0)"
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width=500 height=500></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
//Legend
    var legend = vis.selectAll(".legend")
        .data(color.domain())
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

    legend.append("image")
        .attr("x", 890)
        .attr("y", 70)
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("height", 18)
        .attr("xlink:href",function (d) {
            return "../assets/images/dev/"+d+".png";
        })

    legend.append("text")
        .attr("x", 910)
        .attr("y", 78)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "start")
        .text(function(d) {
                return d;
        });
```